# Cannot start GUI, get a black screen with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, intel-graphics

I just have my new desktop with i5-8600K CPU and Ubuntu 16.04 installed.
I use the Intel GPU. Everything works find at the very beginning.
But after a few updates. It can't not boot to graphic login screen.

I can login with tty1, and I found there maybe something wrong with this log
at /var/log/Xorg.0.log. Could anyone tell me what I should do? Thanks.

```
[     5.891] 
X.Org X Server 1.18.4
Release Date: 2016-07-19
[     5.891] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[     5.891] Build Operating System: Linux 4.4.0-97-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[     5.891] Current Operating System: Linux rba 4.10.0-40-generic #44~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 9 15:37:44 UTC 2017 x86_64
[     5.891] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-40-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=4b978988-84ad-479b-9312-e56bbd57983b ro nomodeset
[     5.891] Build Date: 13 October 2017  01:57:05PM
[     5.891] xorg-server 2:1.18.4-0ubuntu0.7 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[     5.891] Current version of pixman: 0.33.6
[     5.891]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
to make sure that you have the latest version.
[     5.891] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[     5.891] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Thu Nov 23 00:04:31 2017
[     5.891] (==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
[     5.891] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[     5.902] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[     5.902] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen" (0)
[     5.902] (**) |   |-->Monitor "Configured Monitor"
[     5.902] (**) |   |-->Device "Configured Video Device"
[     5.902] (==) Automatically adding devices
[     5.902] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[     5.902] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[     5.902] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[     5.902] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[     5.902]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     5.902] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[     5.902]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     5.902] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[     5.902]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     5.902] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[     5.902]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     5.902] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[     5.902]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     5.902] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    built-ins
[     5.902] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[     5.902] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[     5.902] (II) Loader magic: 0x55852f76edc0
[     5.902] (II) Module ABI versions:
[     5.902]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[     5.902]    X.Org Video Driver: 20.0
[     5.902]    X.Org XInput driver : 22.1
[     5.902]    X.Org Server Extension : 9.0
[     5.903] (++) using VT number 7
[     5.903] (II) systemd-logind: logind integration requires -keeptty and -keeptty was not provided, disabling logind integration
[     5.904] (--) PCI:*(0:0:2:0) 8086:3e92:1458:d000 rev 0, Mem @ 0xf6000000/16777216, 0xe0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x0000f000/64, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[     5.904] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[     5.909] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[     5.936] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     5.936]    compiled for 1.18.4, module version = 1.0.0
[     5.936]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 9.0
[     5.936] (==) AIGLX enabled
[     5.936] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[     5.936] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module vesa
[     5.936] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[     5.936] (II) Unloading vesa
[     5.936] (EE) Failed to load module "vesa" (module does not exist, 0)
[     5.936] (==) Matched intel as autoconfigured driver 0
[     5.936] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 1
[     5.936] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 2
[     5.936] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 3
[     5.936] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[     5.936] (II) LoadModule: "intel"
[     5.936] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
[     5.937] (II) Module intel: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     5.937]    compiled for 1.18.4, module version = 2.99.917
[     5.937]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[     5.937]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 20.0
[     5.937] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[     5.937] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[     5.937] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     5.937]    compiled for 1.18.4, module version = 1.18.4
[     5.937]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[     5.937]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 20.0
[     5.937] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[     5.937] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module fbdev
[     5.937] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[     5.937] (II) Unloading fbdev
[     5.937] (EE) Failed to load module "fbdev" (module does not exist, 0)
[     5.937] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[     5.937] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module vesa
[     5.937] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[     5.937] (II) Unloading vesa
[     5.937] (EE) Failed to load module "vesa" (module does not exist, 0)
[     5.937] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Integrated Graphics Chipsets:
    i810, i810-dc100, i810e, i815, i830M, 845G, 854, 852GM/855GM, 865G,
    915G, E7221 (i915), 915GM, 945G, 945GM, 945GME, Pineview GM,
    Pineview G, 965G, G35, 965Q, 946GZ, 965GM, 965GME/GLE, G33, Q35, Q33,
    GM45, 4 Series, G45/G43, Q45/Q43, G41, B43
[     5.937] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) HD Graphics: 2000-6000
[     5.937] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Graphics: 5100, 6100
[     5.937] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Pro Graphics: 5200, 6200, P6300
[     5.937] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[     5.940] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[     5.940] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[     5.940] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[     5.940] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[     5.940] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[     5.940] (EE) Device(s) detected, but none match those in the config file.
[     5.940] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[     5.940] (EE) no screens found(EE) 
[     5.940] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[     5.940] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[     5.940] (EE) 
[     5.941] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue starts at the "5.936" mark

```
[     5.936] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[     5.936] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module vesa
[     5.936] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[     5.936] (II) Unloading vesa
[     5.936] (EE) Failed to load module "vesa" (module does not exist, 0)
```

This suggests that one of your recent updates either removed, or broke, the module that provides the drivers for the intel GPU. You will probably need to boot into rescue mode (available through the GRUB boot menu), and in that rescue mode check for new package updates and install them. If this does not solve it, you may need to reinstall the Mesa packages (like mesa-utils).

Either way, the issue looks like it would be solved once the intel drivers are correctly installed. Chances are, a hiccup caused this issue, not so much that you did anything wrong (but I am not 100% sure, since I don't know the steps you took previously).

Answer (score 0):

You need to install **kernel 4.15** (or newer)

You can do that this way:

- use this tutorial https://www.askmetutorials.com/2018/01/how-to-install-linux-kernel-415-on.html or any other tutorial to install 4.15 into ubuntu 16+

Or, if you are not able to copy text, you can do:

- Go to another tty by alt+ctrl+f1
- login, use any text-based web browser (because u r not able to copy any text here), for example, **links**

  links http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.15/

and download 3 deb packages.
For me they were:

- linux-headers-4.15.0-041500_4.15.0-041500.201801282230_all.deb
- linux-headers-4.15.0-041500-generic_4.15.0-041500.201801282230_amd64.deb
- linux-image-4.15.0-041500-generic_4.15.0-041500.201801282230_amd64.deb

Then install image first, then generic headers then headers
Then update-grub and reboot.

sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-4.15* linux-image-4.15*

sudo update-grub